# Automating Installation of VS Code Plugins

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm using VS Code with Ubuntu. I have a shell script to automate the installation of my development tools. I can install VS Code but I'm having trouble automating the installation of VS Code plugins e.g. the [Python plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)

Is there an easy way to do this with a shell script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After installing VSCode, it provides a [command line interface](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line). So you can simply install an extension like this:

```
code --install-extension ms-python.python
```

If you have multiple extensions to install, you could create your own extension and bundle them in the "extensionPack" section (*package.json*), [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_extension-packs-revisited).

Comment: You might get the error message "Make sure you use the full extension ID, including the publisher". This message is not exactly helpful and might just mean that you are behind a proxy and have to set it up first.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode provides a command-line interface [[LINK]](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line).

I am sharing how I automate installing VSCode and extensions on my mac.

1: Create a file `setup-vscode` into a specific directory. Include a list of extensions.

2: Go to the directory where `setup-vscode` located. simply type `./setup-vscode` in your terminal.

```
#! /bin/sh
brew bundle --file=- <<EOF
  cask "visual-studio-code"
EOF

export PATH="$HOME/env:$PATH"

code --install-extension aaron-bond.better-comments
code --install-extension anseki.vscode-color
code --install-extension bierner.markdown-mermaid
code --install-extension CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer
code --install-extension dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
code --install-extension eamodio.gitlens
code --install-extension Gruntfuggly.todo-tree
code --install-extension HookyQR.beautify
code --install-extension kddejong.vscode-cfn-lint
code --install-extension markskelton.one-dark-pro-italic
code --install-extension ms-python.python
code --install-extension ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare
code --install-extension naumovs.color-highlight
code --install-extension oderwat.indent-rainbow
code --install-extension Prisma.vscode-graphql
code --install-extension vscodevim.vim
code --install-extension vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons
```